# Calling a variable from string in PHP

Tags: php, variables

i need to call similar variable on shortest way.

```
$test = new stdClass();    
$test->var0=0;    
$test->var1=1;    
$test->var2=2;
```

And now i need to echo all 3 variables in for cycle, not like this:

```
echo $test->var0;   
echo $test->var1;
echo $test->var2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo $test->{'var' . $i};
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved my day :)

Comment: @eddieh accept the answer it will help to other who also facing same issue by click on the left tick